# isotope plugin initial load animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to animate the items so they fade in from 0 instead of growing in size from 0, but cannot figure out how to do this.

For some reason I can't find any reference to doing this in the documentation or on here.

I'm not trying to animate the items when they are clicked, just the initial on load animation of each item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you set the animation mode to use jQuery instead of CSS (can't see which you're using), you could set it to use one type of animation when you initialise the object on page load, then switch it to use the other type of animation on filtering / sorting or whatever.

If that isn't an option then you could go into the isotope js file and modify the transition - it just uses standrad jQuery transitions as far as I know.

Hop that helps?!

Answer (score -1):

Set css class for your itmes: `isotope-item` And for container: `isotope`.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html